# Booting into TWRP temporarily - A Couple of Queries

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, huawei

I'd like to know the following on booting & flashing custom recovery on my
bootloader unlocked **Huawei P9 EVA-L09**:

1. if i **boot** (not flash) into TWRP temporarily, and check it out if it works, will it not change the stock recovery? (i need the stock recovery for now).
2. if i manage to **boot** (again, not flash) an incompatible version of TWRP, will that be an issue or can i just restart the device and it will retain and will be able to boot into **stock** recovery as normal?
3. my last query would be, if a version of TWRP works on my device after I've tested it through **booting** it, is it guaranteed to work once its *successfully* flashed?

thanks!